# Not able to reset the form with mat chips and mat auto-complete - Angular Reactive forms

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using material design for creating a form where I'm using input field with mat-chips and mat-autocomplete, but when I tried to reset the form using form.reset(); it's not working;

HTML

```
 <mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList2>
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let state of selected"
   [selectable]="selectable"
   [removable]="removable"
   (remove)="remove(state)">
   {{state}}
   <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
  <input #input placeholder="Pick a state..."
   [matChipInputFor]="chipList2"
   [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
   (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
   [matAutocomplete]="auto"
   [formControl]="stateCtrl"/>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="add($event); 
   input.value = ''">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" 
    [value]="state">
    {{ state }}
    </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-chip-list>
  </mat-form-field>
 <button mat-button (click)="clear()">clear</button>
```

TS

```
  color =  'primary';
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
  @ViewChild('auto') auto: ElementRef; 
  states = [
  'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas'
  ];
  stateCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredStates: any;
  selected: string[] = [
  'Illinois', 'Missouri'
   ];

 constructor() {
  this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
  this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(null),
  map((name: string) => this.filterStates(name))
  );
  }
 filterStates(val: string) {
 const matches = val ? this.states.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 
 'gi').test(s))
  : this.states;
  return matches.filter(x => !this.selected.find(y => y === x));
 }

 add(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
  if (!event.option) { return; }
 const input = event.source;
 const value = event.option.value;

  if ((value || '').trim()) {
   this.selected.push(value.trim());
  this.stateCtrl.setValue('');
  }
 } 
 remove(state: string): void {
 const index = this.selected.indexOf(state);

 if (index >= 0) {
  this.selected.splice(index, 1);
 }
 }
 clear(){
 this.stateCtrl.setValue('');
 }
```

Even when I try to reset using form.controlName.setValue('');
then also it's not working.

stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-jn5dzm

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue. `setValue` is not triggering with `mat-chip-list` https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10968

Instead use this approach
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-nfyw5u

Comment: No, it's not working. even i want to clear the value as well as remove all chips from the form field

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to clear the input value or the chip list?

Comment: If you want to reset the chip list the empty the `selected` variable by `this.selected = []` and `form.reset()` is not working because you haven't use any form in your html

Answer (score 1):

Here, your formControl name is: stateCtrl.

so all you need to do to reset it is as following:

```
this.selected = []; // making the chipList empty
this.stateCtrl.reset(); // resets the control
this.stateCtrl.markAsPristine();
this.stateCtrl.markAsUntouched();
```

Hope this works, it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `focus` and `blur` attributes as a workaround.

Html:

```html
<input #chipsInput placeholder="Pick a state..."/>
```

TS:

```ts
...

chipsList: string[] = [];
@ViewChild('chipsInput') chipsInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

constructor() { }        
clearAll(): void {
    this.chipsList = []; //clear chips list
    this.chipsInput.nativeElement.focus(); //WORKAROUND to update view
    this.chipsInput.nativeElement.blur(); //Removes focus from input
}   

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several possibilities, to clean chip input, and only this one worked:

```
clearInput(input: HTMLInputElement) {
   input.value = '';
   this.inputControl.setValue('');
}
```